# Is it ok to use col class inside col class in bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to draw a line below a paragraph with `hr` element. The propbelem is that the `p` element has 15px padding in bootstrap but the hr element spans to the full available width. The line below the paragraph extends 15px left and 15 right to the paragraph's width. So I just did the following:

```
             <div class="row">
              <div class="col-lg-12 text-justify">
                <p> 
                  Some text is here.
                </p>

              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12"> <div class="col-lg-12"><hr></div></div>
              </div>
```

I nested `col-lg-12` directly inside `col-lg-12`. But in bootstrap we ought to nest `.col` inside `.row` classes. So is it okay  use col class inside col class here?

Comment: "Is it okay?". The browser will not complain, but its not a good practice. Just add a custom class and give the padding.

Comment: Does it achieve the layout you desire? There aren't any rules. Do what you like.

Comment: it might not count that and apply everything as per the wrapper..i would suggest using flexbox in such a case

Comment: Actually the question is wrong. There is no padding to paragraphs. I mistakenly nested `.row` inside `.row` directly. After correcting it I no longer need to nest `.col` inside `.col` now. Should I delete the question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**No.** It's not a Bootstrap best practice since as you mentioned col should be inside row.. The effect will be extra spacing on the left and right side of the inner col. The inner columns will wrap and not layout horizontally as expected.

> "content must be placed within columns and only columns may be
>   immediate children of rows"